# Scrollbar por ambos lados

Tags: flutter, scrollbar

Un Scrollbar con configuración para que este del lado izquierdo, pero se muestra por ambos lados en PWA, cuando se hace el scroll.

```
             Scrollbar(
                controller: scroll0,
                scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.left,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: Curvas.radiusA15,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: scroll0,
                    child: Column(
                      children: listWidget,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]